# Store promise resolved in template but not in controller

Tags: ember.js

I have a select box with a list of users that I get from the store. I have a method on the controller where I try to get an initial user for the selectbox. No matter what I do I can't seem to get any user record to resolve on the method but the users show up fine in the selectbox. Can someone explain what I'm missing? Thank you in advance for the help.

Controller:

```
App.TodoModuleController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  users: Em.computed -> @store.findAll 'user'

  selectedUser: Em.computed 'users', ->   
    @get('users').objectAt(1)
    # There are 4 users in the db. Just using 1 for a test.

    # I also tried
    # @get('users').then (users)->
    #   users.objectAt(1)

  selectedUserDidChange: Em.observer 'selectedUser', ->
    if @get 'selectedUser' then @assignUser()

  assignUser: ->
    model = @get 'model'
    model.set 'assigneeId', @get('selectedUser').get('id')
    unless model.save()
      console.log 'Error: TodoModuleController.assignUser'
```

Template:

```
{{view Em.Select content=users selection=selectedUser optionValuePath='content.id' optionLabelPath='content.firstName'}}
```

**SOLUTION (thanks to Hrishi):**

Todo Model:

```
App.Todo = DS.Model.extend
  text: DS.attr 'string'
  assignee: DS.belongsTo 'user', inverse: null
```

Todo Controller:

```
App.TodoModuleController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  users: Em.computed -> @store.findAll 'user'

  assignedUserDidChange: Em.observer 'assignee', ->
    if @get 'assignee' then @assignNewUser()

  assignNewUser: ->
    unless @get('model').save()
      console.log 'Error: TodoModuleController.assignUser'
```

Select Box:

```
{{view Em.Select content=users selection=assignee optionValuePath='content.id' optionLabelPath='content.firstName'}}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't resolving the users in the route?  It would make this significantly easier

Comment: Totally agree. The `setupController` hook is the way to go. This removes the need for the computed property on `selectedUser`.

Comment: I very much agree. The reason I haven't done that here is that I don't have a route for this controller/resource.

Comment: I know this is outside the scope of the question but is this type of thing bad to do? I have this "todos" module that is on many different pages and belongs to many different resources. Would it be the best practice to create a component and pass in the: 'todos', 'parent', and 'users'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computed properties are not computed until someone (in your case, the template) tries to access them, in other words, they are computed lazily. Since the template tries to access them, the `users` array will get populated and you can see it on the page when you click on your select box. The way I would do this would be to put an attribute on the model called `assignee` and bind the view's selection directly to that.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the help. That is great to know. Could you give an example of putting the assignee on the model? Do you mean on the TodoModuleController model?

Comment: Yes. So you would have a model like `App.Modelname= DS.Model.extend({assignee: DS.attr()});`. If this is the backing model for your controller, you just say `value=assignee` and an `optionValuePath="content.id"` on your Ember.Select.